# Easy way to combine two lists into a lookup KVP that maps between the two lists

Tags: c#, lookup-tables

I have two lists, lets say

```
    OtherColors = Color[]
    {
        Color.FromRgb(1,0,0),
        Color.FromRgb(0,0,1),
        Color.FromRgb(1,0,15),
    };

    Colors = Color[]
    {
        Color.FromRgb(1,4,4),
        Color.FromRgb(5,6,66),
        Color.FromRgb(4,5,7),
        Color.FromRgb(7,5,8),
        Color.FromRgb(2,9,2),
        Color.FromRgb(4,2,190),
        Color.FromRgb(5,5,2),
        Color.FromRgb(180,5,7),
        Color.FromRgb(5,9,171),
    };
```

What's the fastest / easiest way to combine them into a dictionary that serves as a lookup table, so that each item in the short list is repeated three times as the value and each item from the longer list is just inserted as the key at the same place as it is in the longer list?

Something that ends up looking like

```
ColorLookup = new Dictionary<Color, Color>
{
    {Color.FromRgb(1,4,4), Color.FromRgb(1,0,0)},
    {Color.FromRgb(5,6,66), Color.FromRgb(1,0,0)},
    {Color.FromRgb(4,5,7), Color.FromRgb(1,0,0)},
    {Color.FromRgb(7,5,8), Color.FromRgb(0,0,1)},
    {Color.FromRgb(2,9,2), Color.FromRgb(0,0,1)},
    {Color.FromRgb(4,2,190),Color.FromRgb(0,0,1)},
    {Color.FromRgb(5,5,2), Color.FromRgb(1,0,15)},
    {Color.FromRgb(180,5,7),Color.FromRgb(1,0,15)},
    {Color.FromRgb(5,9,171),Color.FromRgb(1,0,15)},
};
```

I know this is simple but I'm blanking on it...

Comment: Two foreach loops. The outer loops through OtherColors and the inner one loops through colors. Inside the inner loop, you add the current otherColor along with current color

Comment: I was hoping something clever like using ``Enumerable.Zip`` and ``Enumerable.Repeat`` :(

Comment: Also that would repeat the larger list, which I don't want.

Comment: That's not going to work as `Dictionary` will not allow you to have duplicate keys.  Do you actually want `Dictionary<Color, List<Color>>` or something similar instead?  Or maybe `List<Tuple<Color, Color>>`?

Comment: Ooops, it's fine if the values / keys are switched, I'll update the questions with correct code.

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti A single foreach with an incrementing value would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wont get much faster than a simple loop. 
Easiest is arguable, but i prefer linq-solutions.

```
var ColorLookup = Colors.Select((c,i) => new { Key = c, Value = OtherColors[i / OtherColors.Length]}).ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v=> v.Value);
```

[Test here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/REodK6)

Comment: Sweet, thanks. There's one ) missing before the .ToDictionary and % OtherColors.Length should actually be just 3, since the real array is longer and I want them in groups of 3

Comment: @gakera I edited my answer, i was inciorrectly using % (modulo) but it should be / (divide)

Answer (score 1):

Not as cool as you were hoping, but it works, provided these lists stay exactly as they are:

```
var output = new Dictionary<Color, Color>();
for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
{
    output.Add(colors[i], otherColors[(int)Math.Floor(i / 3M)]);
}
```

You could parameterize it to handle lists of different sizes and do some bounds checking.

Comment: You do not need to write `(int)Math.Floor(i / 3M)` It is enough to write `i/3`since both i and 3 are integers it will  return an integer (which is basically the floor)